# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]' streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: catatan.snapshots(),
                    builder: (_, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Column(
                          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((e) =>
                                  Data(e.data()['judul'], e.data()['isi']))
                              .toList(),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text('Data Kosong');
                      }})
```

I get an error in **['judul']** and **['isi']**

**Error message:
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.**

can you guys help me :)

Comment: May those two have to be `e.data['judul'], e.data['isi']` insted of `e.data()['judul'], e.data()['isi']` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data['key']` operator you want to use is only available for a `Map<String, dynamic>` type variable. But if not typed the method `data()` will return an object of type `Object`.

You will have to cast the result like this:

```dart
snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((e) {
  final data = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return Data(data['judul'], data['isi']);
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Type your data to `Map<String, dynamic>`
Refer example:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: catatan.snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> chatSnapshot) {
                if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                }
                return ListView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  children:
                      chatSnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return Text(data['judul'])
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
```